# Android Show First launch Guide Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, styles, showcaseview

[image]

Well I want to show like this guide dialog message at first launch.
What is that I dont know

I have try with this code but not looking like it.

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
<item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

and in activity

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogmesaj);

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/showcase-view/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is showcase view mehmet. Please check out library and example code from **[here.](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)**

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Comment: Hello Adnan how can I use this. because I have downloaded files from your link but I can not use it. I tried like Google map (Google Play service) import add jar files and etc. but I cant succesed. Do you know any tutorial or example about how to use Showcase view. I dont Understant from Alex Curran

Comment: You have to import "library" as library into your project. You can find  "sample" project on given repository.